# Python config file: setting paths for a script

Tags: python

I'm writing a bioinformatic tool that upon set up I would like to check certain paths to specific files.

I also have some cython code I would like to package into the script. I'm currently using a `setup.py` and `distutils` for compilation

Is it possible to add a config file to my setup.py that would check four paths?

I'm thinking a .ini config file like this

```
[myScript_PATHS]
myScript = $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR # actually how do I do this? link to the working dir? 
fasta = /home/myName/reference/human/hg19.fasta
prepro = $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/myScript_preprocessing
feats = $CURRENT_WORKING_DIR/myScript_features
```

So when the user downloads and decompresses my tarball. The user will run `python setup.py`

How do I ensure the following:

- my cython .pyx files are compiled in place?
- the if the paths do not exist create them

Thanks! I'm a biologist turned programmer so I'm unfamiliar with these details of packaging a script.

Comment: It should not be a direct solution for your problem but I believe that makefiles can be more flexible to solve that kind of problems. In a makefile, you can gather any command you want in a simple script. Have you already tried those?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am considering a makefile. I can't find a good tutorial for them for python. Do you know of one?

Answer (score 0):

One answer 
 - my cython .pyx files are compiled in place?

Using the distutil `setup.cfg` I put this in the file

```
[build_ext]
inplace=1
```